# NullPointerException ao salvar um objeto

Tags: java, jsf, hibernate

Tenho um método salvarRegistro e nesse método eu salvo a empresa e o endereço dela, ele salva primeiramente a empresa, mas ao salvar o endereço dela ocorre um NullPointerException

**Entidade Endereço Pessoa**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "enderecopessoa")
public class EnderecoPessoa implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private EnderecoId id;
private Endereco endereco;
private String devolucao;
private String devolucaoDescritivo;
private String correspondencia;
private String correspondeciaDescritivo;
private String emailAtualizacaoCadastral;
private Date dataAtualizacaoCadastral;
private Boolean atualizacaoCadastralSic=false;

public EnderecoPessoa() {
    id = new EnderecoId();
    endereco = new Endereco();
}

public EnderecoPessoa(String codigoPessoa, String idTipoEndereco) {
    id = new EnderecoId(codigoPessoa, idTipoEndereco);
    endereco = new Endereco();
}

public EnderecoPessoa(String codigoPessoa, TipoEndereco tipoEndereco) {
    id = new EnderecoId(codigoPessoa, tipoEndereco);
    endereco = new Endereco();
}

@EmbeddedId
public EnderecoId getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(EnderecoId id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Embedded
public Endereco getEndereco() {
    return endereco;
}

public void setEndereco(Endereco endereco) {
    this.endereco = endereco;
}

@Column(length = 1)
public String getDevolucao() {
    return devolucao;
}

public void setDevolucao(String devolucao) {
    this.devolucao = devolucao;
}

@Transient
public String getDevolucaoDescritivo() {
    if (devolucao == null) {
        return "NÃO DEFINIDO!";
    }
    if (devolucao.equals("N")) {
        return "Não";
    } else {
        if (devolucao.equals("S")) {
            return "Sim";
        } else {
            devolucaoDescritivo = "NÃO DEFINIDO!";
            return devolucaoDescritivo;
        }
    }
}

@Column(length = 1)
public String getCorrespondencia() {
    return correspondencia;
}

public void setCorrespondencia(String correspondencia) {
    this.correspondencia = correspondencia;
}

@Transient
public String getCorrespondeciaDescritivo() {
    if (correspondencia.equals("S")) {
        return "Sim";
    } else {
        if (correspondencia.equals("N")) {
            return "Não";
        } else {
            correspondeciaDescritivo = "NÃO DEFINIDO!";
            return correspondeciaDescritivo;
        }
    }
}

@Column(name = "emailAtualizacaoCadastral", length = 60)
public String getEmailAtualizacaoCadastral() {
    return emailAtualizacaoCadastral;
}

public void setEmailAtualizacaoCadastral(String emailAtualizacaoCadastral) {
    this.emailAtualizacaoCadastral = emailAtualizacaoCadastral;
}

@Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
public Date getDataAtualizacaoCadastral() {
    return dataAtualizacaoCadastral;
}

public void setDataAtualizacaoCadastral(Date dataAtualizacaoCadastral) {
    this.dataAtualizacaoCadastral = dataAtualizacaoCadastral;
}

public Boolean getAtualizacaoCadastralSic() {
    return atualizacaoCadastralSic;
}

public void setAtualizacaoCadastralSic(Boolean atualizacaoCadastralSic) {
    this.atualizacaoCadastralSic = atualizacaoCadastralSic;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 7;
    hash = 71 * hash + (this.id != null ? this.id.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "EnderecoPessoa{" + "id=pessoa{" + id.getPessoa().getCodigo() + "},tipo{" + id.getTipoEndereco().getIdtipoendereco() + "};"
            + "endereco=" + endereco.getEnderecoDescritivo() + ";"
            + "devolucao=" + devolucao + ";"
            + "correspondencia=" + correspondencia + '}';
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    final EnderecoPessoa other = (EnderecoPessoa) obj;
    if (this.id != other.id && (this.id == null || !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
        return false;
    }
    if (this.endereco != other.endereco && (this.endereco == null || !this.endereco.equals(other.endereco))) {
        return false;
    }
    if ((this.devolucao == null) ? (other.devolucao != null) : !this.devolucao.equals(other.devolucao)) {
        return false;
    }
    if ((this.correspondencia == null) ? (other.correspondencia != null) : !this.correspondencia.equals(other.correspondencia)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

}
```

**Entidade Empresa**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "empresa")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "codigo")
public class Empresa extends Pessoa implements Serializable {

private Long faixa;
private SituacaoRegistro situacaoRegistro;
private Date dataRegistro;
private String nomeFantasia;
private String antigaRazaoSocial;
private BigDecimal valorCapitalMatriz;
private BigDecimal valorCapital;
private String moedaCapital = "R$";
private Date dataCapital;
private Date dataCapitalMatriz;
private String documentoCapital;
private String categoria = "M";
private String tipo;
private String objeto;
private String numeroProcesso;
private Long numeroRegistro;
private Date dataVisto;
private String registroAntigo;
private Boolean entidadeClasse = false;
private List<ResponsabilidadeTecnica> responsaveisAtivos;
private List<ResponsabilidadeTecnica> responsaveisAtivosSemDebito;
private String categoriaDetalhada;
private String tipoDetalhado;
private String entidadeClasseDetalhada;
private String cnpjMatriz;
private String classe;
private List<ResponsabilidadeTecnica> responsaveis;
private List<Socio> socios;
private List<Art> arts;
private Endereco endereco;
private List<ArtWeb> artsWeb;
private Long ultimoAnoPago;
private boolean isenta;
private boolean subJudice;
private String isentaDetalhado;
private String subJudiceDetalhado;
private List<AtividadeEmpresa> atividades;
private String atividadesString;
private String objetoComEspaco;
private boolean convenioGoverno;
private String tipoPessoaJuridica;
private String subtipoPessoaJuridica;
private Boolean isencaoTaxa;
private String documentoIsencaoTaxa;
private Profissional profissionalResponsavelPeloRegistro;

public Empresa() {
    this.isenta = false;
    this.subJudice = false;
}

public Empresa(String codigo) {
    super.setCodigo(codigo);
    this.isenta = false;
    this.subJudice = false;
}

// GETTERS E SETTERS
public Long getFaixa() {
    return this.faixa;
}

public void setFaixa(Long faixa) {
    this.faixa = faixa;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "idsituacaoregistro")
public SituacaoRegistro getSituacaoRegistro() {
    return situacaoRegistro;
}

public void setSituacaoRegistro(SituacaoRegistro situacaoRegistro) {
    this.situacaoRegistro = situacaoRegistro;
}

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "dataregistro", length = 13)
public Date getDataRegistro() {
    return dataRegistro;
}

public void setDataRegistro(Date dataRegistro) {
    this.dataRegistro = dataRegistro;
}

@Column(name = "nomefantasia", length = 100)
public String getNomeFantasia() {
    return nomeFantasia;
}

public void setNomeFantasia(String nomeFantasia) {
    this.nomeFantasia = nomeFantasia;
}

@Column(name = "antigarazaosocial", length = 60)
public String getAntigaRazaoSocial() {
    return antigaRazaoSocial;
}

public void setAntigaRazaoSocial(String antigaRazaoSocial) {
    this.antigaRazaoSocial = antigaRazaoSocial;
}

@Column(name = "valorcapitalmatriz", precision = 15, scale = 3)
public BigDecimal getValorCapitalMatriz() {
    return valorCapitalMatriz;
}

public void setValorCapitalMatriz(BigDecimal valorCapitalMatriz) {
    this.valorCapitalMatriz = valorCapitalMatriz;
}

@Column(name = "valorcapital", precision = 15, scale = 3)
public BigDecimal getValorCapital() {
    return valorCapital;
}

public void setValorCapital(BigDecimal valorCapital) {
    this.valorCapital = valorCapital;
}

@Column(name = "moedacapital", length = 4)
public String getMoedaCapital() {
    return moedaCapital;
}

public void setMoedaCapital(String moedaCapital) {
    this.moedaCapital = moedaCapital;
}

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "datacapital", length = 13)
public Date getDataCapital() {
    return dataCapital;
}

public void setDataCapital(Date dataCapital) {
    this.dataCapital = dataCapital;
}

@Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
public Date getDataCapitalMatriz() {
    return dataCapitalMatriz;
}

public void setDataCapitalMatriz(Date dataCapitalMatriz) {
    this.dataCapitalMatriz = dataCapitalMatriz;
}

@Column(name = "documentocapital", length = 20)
public String getDocumentoCapital() {
    return documentoCapital;
}

public void setDocumentoCapital(String documentoCapital) {
    this.documentoCapital = documentoCapital;
}

@Column(name = "numeroprocesso", length = 13)
public String getNumeroProcesso() {
    return numeroProcesso;
}

public void setNumeroProcesso(String numeroProcesso) {
    this.numeroProcesso = numeroProcesso;
}

public Long getNumeroRegistro() {
    return numeroRegistro;
}

public void setNumeroRegistro(Long numeroRegistro) {
    this.numeroRegistro = numeroRegistro;
}

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "datavisto", length = 13)
public Date getDataVisto() {
    return dataVisto;
}

public void setDataVisto(Date dataVisto) {
    this.dataVisto = dataVisto;
}

@Column(name = "registroantigo", length = 10)
public String getRegistroAntigo() {
    return registroAntigo;
}

public void setRegistroAntigo(String registroAntigo) {
    this.registroAntigo = registroAntigo;
}

@Column(name = "entidadeclasse")
public Boolean getEntidadeClasse() {
    return entidadeClasse;
}

public void setEntidadeClasse(Boolean entidadeClasse) {
    this.entidadeClasse = entidadeClasse;
}

public String getCnpjMatriz() {
    return cnpjMatriz;
}

public void setCnpjMatriz(String cnpjMatriz) {
    this.cnpjMatriz = cnpjMatriz;
}

@Column(length = 10)
public String getClasse() {
    return classe;
}

public void setClasse(String classe) {
    this.classe = classe;
}

@Column(name = "categoria", length = 1)
public String getCategoria() {
    return this.categoria;
}

public void setCategoria(String categoria) {
    this.categoria = categoria;
}

@Column(name = "tipo", length = 1)
public String getTipo() {
    return this.tipo;
}

public void setTipo(String tipo) {
    this.tipo = tipo;
}

@Lob
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.StringClobType")
public String getObjeto() {
    return this.objeto;
}

public void setObjeto(String objeto) {
    this.objeto = objeto;
}

@Transient
public String getCategoriaDetalhada() {
    categoriaDetalhada = "Não Identificado";
    if (categoria.equals("M")) {
        categoriaDetalhada = "Matriz";
    } else if (categoria.equals("F")) {
        categoriaDetalhada = "Filial";
    } else if (categoria.equals("O")) {
        categoriaDetalhada = "Outros";
    }
    return categoriaDetalhada;
}

public void setCategoriaDetalhada(String categoriaDetalhada) {
    this.categoriaDetalhada = categoriaDetalhada;
}

@Transient
public String getTipoDetalhado() {
    tipoDetalhado = "Não Identificado";
    if (tipo != null) {
        if (tipo.equals("1")) {
            tipoDetalhado = "Pública";
        } else if (tipo.equals("2")) {
            tipoDetalhado = "Privada";
        } else if (tipo.equals("3")) {
            tipoDetalhado = "Mista";
        } else if (tipo.equals("4")) {
            tipoDetalhado = "Outras";
        }
    }
    return tipoDetalhado;
}

public void setTipoDetalhado(String tipoDetalhado) {
    this.tipoDetalhado = tipoDetalhado;
}

@Transient
public String getEntidadeClasseDetalhada() {
    entidadeClasseDetalhada = "";
    if ((entidadeClasse != null) && (entidadeClasse)) {
        entidadeClasseDetalhada = "Sim";
    } else {
        entidadeClasseDetalhada = "Não";
    }

    return entidadeClasseDetalhada;
}

public void setEntidadeClasseDetalhada(String entidadeClasseDetalhada) {
    this.entidadeClasseDetalhada = entidadeClasseDetalhada;
}

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "pk.empresa", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
public List<ResponsabilidadeTecnica> getResponsaveis() {
    if (responsaveis == null) {
        responsaveis = new ArrayList<ResponsabilidadeTecnica>();
    }
    return responsaveis;
}

public void setResponsaveis(List<ResponsabilidadeTecnica> responsaveis) {
    this.responsaveis = responsaveis;
}

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "pk.empresa")
public List<Socio> getSocios() {
    if (socios == null) {
        socios = new ArrayList<Socio>();
    }
    return socios;
}

public void setSocios(List<Socio> socios) {
    this.socios = socios;
}

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "empresaContratada")
public List<Art> getArts() {
    if (arts == null) {
        arts = new ArrayList<Art>();
    }
    return arts;
}

public void setArts(List<Art> arts) {
    this.arts = arts;
}

@Transient
public Endereco getEndereco() {
    return endereco;
}

public void setEndereco(Endereco endereco) {
    this.endereco = endereco;
}

public Long getUltimoAnoPago() {
    return ultimoAnoPago;
}

public void setUltimoAnoPago(Long ultimoAnoPago) {
    this.ultimoAnoPago = ultimoAnoPago;
}

@Transient
public String getObjetoComEspaco() {
    objetoComEspaco = objeto.concat("\n\n");
    return objetoComEspaco;
}

public void setObjetoComEspaco(String objetoComEspaco) {
    this.objetoComEspaco = objetoComEspaco;
}

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "empresaContratada")
public List<ArtWeb> getArtsWeb() {
    if (artsWeb == null) {
        artsWeb = new ArrayList<ArtWeb>();
    }
    return artsWeb;
}

public void setArtsWeb(List<ArtWeb> artsWeb) {
    this.artsWeb = artsWeb;
}

@Transient
public List<ArtWeb> getArtsWebAtivas() {
    List<ArtWeb> artsWebAtivas = new ArrayList<ArtWeb>();
    boolean temArt = false;
    for (ArtWeb aw : getArtsWeb()) {
        for (Art a : getArts()) {
            if (a.getNumeroArt().equals(aw.getNumeroArt())) {
                temArt = true;
            }
        }
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTime(new Date());
        c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -15);
        if (!temArt
                && aw.getDataElaboracao() != null
                && aw.getDataElaboracao().after(c.getTime())) {
            artsWebAtivas.add(aw);
        }
        temArt = false;
    }
    return artsWebAtivas;
}

@Transient
public List<Art> getArtsRegistradas() {
    List<Art> artsRegistradas = new ArrayList<Art>();
    for (Art a : getArts()) {
        if (a.getDataEntrada() != null) {
            artsRegistradas.add(a);
        }
    }
    return artsRegistradas;
}

@Transient
public List<ArtWeb> getArtsNaoRegistradas() {
    List<ArtWeb> artsNaoRegistradas = new ArrayList<ArtWeb>();
    for (ArtWeb aw : getArtsWeb()) {
        for (Art a : getArts()) {
            if (a.getNumeroArt().equals(aw.getNumeroArt())
                    && a.getDataEntrada() == null) {
                artsNaoRegistradas.add(aw);
            }
        }
    }
    return artsNaoRegistradas;
}

@Transient
public List<Art> getArtsManuaisNaoRegistradas() {
    List<Art> artsManuaisNaoRegistradas = new ArrayList<Art>();
    Boolean temArt = false;
    for (Art a : getArts()) {
        for (ArtWeb aw : getArtsWeb()) {
            if (a.getNumeroArt().equals(aw.getNumeroArt())) {
                temArt = true;
            }
        }
        if (!temArt && a.getDataEntrada() == null) {
            artsManuaisNaoRegistradas.add(a);
        }
    }
    return artsManuaisNaoRegistradas;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    String resps = "";
    if (!getResponsaveis().isEmpty()) {
        for (ResponsabilidadeTecnica rt : getResponsaveis()) {
            resps += " " + rt.getPk().getInicioResponsabilidadeFormatado() + " - " + rt.getPk().getProfissional().getNome();
        }
    }
    return "Empresa{" + "codigo=" + super.getCodigo() + ";"
            + "cpfCnpj=" + super.getCpfCnpj() + ";"
            + "nome=" + super.getNome() + ";"
            + "email=" + super.getEmail() + ";"
            + "site=" + super.getSite() + ";"
            + "faixa=" + (faixa != null ? faixa.toString() : "VAZIO") + ";"
            + "situacaoRegistro=" + (situacaoRegistro != null ? situacaoRegistro.getDescricao() : "VAZIO") + ";"
            + "dataRegistro=" + dataRegistro + ";"
            + "nomeFantasia=" + nomeFantasia + ";"
            + "antigaRazaoSocial=" + antigaRazaoSocial + ";"
            + "valorCapitalMatriz=" + valorCapitalMatriz + ";"
            + "valorCapital=" + valorCapital + ";"
            + "moedaCapital=" + moedaCapital + ";"
            + "dataCapital=" + dataCapital + ";"
            + "dataCapitalMatriz=" + dataCapitalMatriz + ";"
            + "documentoCapital=" + documentoCapital + ";"
            + "categoria=" + categoria + ";"
            + "tipo=" + tipo + ";"
            + "objeto=" + objeto + ";"
            + "numeroProcesso=" + numeroProcesso + ";"
            + "numeroRegistro=" + numeroRegistro + ";"
            + "dataVisto=" + dataVisto + ";"
            + "registroAntigo=" + registroAntigo + ";"
            + "entidadeClasse=" + entidadeClasse + ";"
            + "categoriaDetalhada=" + categoriaDetalhada + ";"
            + "tipoDetalhado=" + tipoDetalhado + ";"
            + "entidadeClasseDetalhada=" + entidadeClasseDetalhada + ";"
            + "cnpjMatriz=" + cnpjMatriz + ";"
            + "classe=" + classe + ";"
            + "responsaveis=" + resps + ";"
            + "responsavelPeloRegistro=" + profissionalResponsavelPeloRegistro + ";"
            + '}';
}

@Transient
public List<ResponsabilidadeTecnica> getResponsaveisAtivos() {
    List<ResponsabilidadeTecnica> resps = new ArrayList<ResponsabilidadeTecnica>();
    for (ResponsabilidadeTecnica rt : getResponsaveis()) {
        if (rt.getPk().getProfissional().getSituacaoRegistro() != null && rt.getPk().getProfissional().getSituacaoRegistro().getIdSituacaoRegistro().equals("2")) {
            if ((rt.getFimContrato() == null || rt.getFimContrato().after(new Date()))
                    && (rt.getFimResponsabilidade() == null || rt.getFimResponsabilidade().after(new Date()))) {
                resps.add(rt);
            }
        }
    }
    responsaveisAtivos = resps;
    return responsaveisAtivos;
}

public void setResponsaveisAtivos(List<ResponsabilidadeTecnica> responsaveisAtivos) {
    this.responsaveisAtivos = responsaveisAtivos;
}

@Transient
public List<ResponsabilidadeTecnica> getResponsaveisAtivosSemDebito() {
    responsaveisAtivosSemDebito = new ArrayList<ResponsabilidadeTecnica>();
    for (ResponsabilidadeTecnica rt : getResponsaveisAtivos()) {
        if (PessoaUtil.pessoaEmDiaComAnuidade(rt.getPk().getProfissional())) {
            responsaveisAtivosSemDebito.add(rt);
        }
    }
    return responsaveisAtivosSemDebito;
}

public void setResponsaveisAtivosSemDebito(List<ResponsabilidadeTecnica> responsaveisAtivosSemDebito) {
    this.responsaveisAtivosSemDebito = responsaveisAtivosSemDebito;
}

@Transient
public String getItensHint() {
    String retorno = "";
    for (Art a : getArts()) {
        retorno += "Nº ART: " + a.getNumeroArt() + "\nData Entrada: " + a.getDataEntrada() + "\nData Pagamento: " + a.getDataPagamento() + "\nNº Recibo: " + a.getNumeroRecibo()
 //+ "\nValor Obra/Serviço: " + String.format("%5.2f", a.getValorObraServico()) 
                + "\nValor Pago: " + String.format("%5.2f", a.getValorPago())
                + "\nEndereço: " + a.getEnderecoObraServico().getEnderecoDescritivo() + "\nContratante: " + a.getContrato().getIdentificacaoContratante().getNome();
    }
    return retorno;
}

@Transient
public List<Art> getArtsNaoBaixadas() {
    List<Art> artsNaoBaixadas = new ArrayList<Art>();
    for (Art a : getArts()) {
        if (a.getDataBaixa() == null) {
            artsNaoBaixadas.add(a);
        }
    }
    return artsNaoBaixadas;
}

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "pk.empresa")
public List<AtividadeEmpresa> getAtividades() {
    if (atividades == null) {
        atividades = new ArrayList<AtividadeEmpresa>();
    }
    return atividades;
}

public void setAtividades(List<AtividadeEmpresa> atividades) {
    this.atividades = atividades;
}

@Transient
public String getAtividadesString() {
    atividadesString = "";
    for (AtividadeEmpresa ae : atividades) {
        if (!atividadesString.isEmpty()) {
            atividadesString += ", ";
        }
        atividadesString += ae.getPk().getTipoAtividadeEmpresa().getDescricao();
    }
    return atividadesString;
}

public void setAtividadesString(String atividadesString) {
    this.atividadesString = atividadesString;
}

public boolean isIsenta() {
    return isenta;
}

public void setIsenta(boolean isenta) {
    this.isenta = isenta;
}

public boolean isSubJudice() {
    return subJudice;
}

public void setSubJudice(boolean subJudice) {
    this.subJudice = subJudice;
}

@ManyToOne
public Profissional getProfissionalResponsavelPeloRegistro() {
    return profissionalResponsavelPeloRegistro;
}

public void setProfissionalResponsavelPeloRegistro(Profissional profissionalResponsavelPeloRegistro) {
    this.profissionalResponsavelPeloRegistro = profissionalResponsavelPeloRegistro;
}

@Transient
public String getIsentaDetalhado() {
    if (isenta) {
        isentaDetalhado = "Sim";
    } else {
        isentaDetalhado = "Não";
    }
    return isentaDetalhado;
}

public void setIsentaDetalhado(String isentaDetalhado) {
    this.isentaDetalhado = isentaDetalhado;
}

@Transient
public String getSubJudiceDetalhado() {
    if (subJudice) {
        subJudiceDetalhado = "Sim";
    } else {
        subJudiceDetalhado = "Não";
    }
    return subJudiceDetalhado;
}

public void setSubJudiceDetalhado(String subJudiceDetalhado) {
    this.subJudiceDetalhado = subJudiceDetalhado;
}

@Transient
public Socio getSocioPrincipal() {
    Socio socioPrincipal = null;
    BigDecimal cotaAtual = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    for (Socio socio : socios) {
        if (socioPrincipal == null) {
            socioPrincipal = socio;
        } else {
            if (socio.getCota() != null && socio.getCota().compareTo(cotaAtual) == 1 && socio.getDataSaida() == null) {
                cotaAtual = socio.getCota();
                socioPrincipal = socio;
            }
        }
    }
    return socioPrincipal;
}

public boolean isConvenioGoverno() {
    return convenioGoverno;
}

public void setConvenioGoverno(boolean convenioGoverno) {
    this.convenioGoverno = convenioGoverno;
}

@Transient
public boolean isFilial() {
    if (getCodigo().endsWith("TPPI")) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getCategoria() != null && !getCategoria().equals("M")) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

@Transient
public boolean isMatriz() {
    if (!isFilial()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

@Transient
public boolean isMeiaAnuidade() {
    //Art. 14. A anuidade da pessoa jurídica que possuir filial, agência, sucursal, escritório
    //de representação em circunscrição diferente daquela onde se localiza sua matriz corresponderá à
    //metade do valor previsto para a matriz, desde que não possua capital social destacado.
    if (isFilial()) {
        if (getValorCapital() == null || getValorCapital().compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) <= 0) {
            return true;
        }
    }
//    boolean temEnderecoPI = false;
//        for (EnderecoPessoa e : getEnderecosPessoas()) {
//        if (e.getEndereco() != null && e.getEndereco().getUf() != null && e.getEndereco().getUf().equals("PI")) {
//        temEnderecoPI = true;
//   }
//  }
//        if (!temEnderecoPI && !getEnderecosPessoas().isEmpty()) {
//            return true;
//        }
    return false;
}

public String getTipoPessoaJuridica() {
    return tipoPessoaJuridica;
}

public void setTipoPessoaJuridica(String tipoPessoaJuridica) {
    this.tipoPessoaJuridica = tipoPessoaJuridica;
}

public String getSubtipoPessoaJuridica() {
    return subtipoPessoaJuridica;
}

public void setSubtipoPessoaJuridica(String subtipoPessoaJuridica) {
    this.subtipoPessoaJuridica = subtipoPessoaJuridica;
}

public Boolean getIsencaoTaxa() {
    return isencaoTaxaArt;
}

public void setIsencaoTaxa(Boolean isencaoTaxa) {
    this.isencaoTaxa = isencaoTaxa;
}

public String getDocumentoIsencaoTaxaArt() {
    return documentoIsencaoTaxa;
}

public void setDocumentoIsencaoTaxa(String documentoIsencaoTaxa) {
    this.documentoIsencaoTaxa = documentoIsencaoTaxa;
}
```

**Método salvarRegistro**

```
  public void salvarRegistro() {
       Object uc = empresaDao.query("SELECT codigo FROM pessoa WHERE codigo LIKE '%PA' ORDER BY codigo DESC LIMIT 1");
   String ultimoNumeroS = uc.toString().substring(0, 10);
   Long ultimoNumero = Long.parseLong(ultimoNumeroS);
   Long proximoNumero = ultimoNumero + 1;
   ultimoNumeroS = StringUtils.leftPad(proximoNumero.toString(), 10, "0");
   String proximoCodigo = ultimoNumeroS + "PA";

   empresa.setCodigo(proximoCodigo);
   empresa.setEmail(empresa.getEmail().toLowerCase());
   empresa.setProfissionalResponsavelPeloRegistro((Profissional) profissionalLogado);

   empresaDao.salvar(empresa);
   enderecoEmpresa.getId().setPessoa(empresa);
   enderecoPessoaDao.salvar(enderecoEmpresa);

   for(ArquivoRegistroOnlineEmpresa aroe : arquivosRegistroOnlineEmpresa) {
        aroe.setEmpresa(empresa);
        arquivoRegistroOnlineEmpresaDao.atualizar(aroe);
   }
  }
```

**Instancia de enderecoEmpresa**

```
@PostConstruct
public void inicializar() {
    // OCULTADO

    enderecoEmpresa = new EnderecoPessoa();
    empresa = new Empresa();

    obterTiposPessoaJuridica();
    obterCategorias();
}
```

**DaoGenericImp**

[Link para o DaoGenericImpl](https://pastebin.com/JT03x3Bj)

**StackTrace**

[Link para o StackTrace](https://pastebin.com/iSSK1Q7p)

**EndereçoPessoaDaoImpl**

[Link para a Implementação do EndereçoPessoaDaoImpl](https://pastebin.com/PwM2uSF5)

Comment: Bom dia, Juliana! Edite sua pergunta para incluir a stacktrace completa do erro, assim fica mais fácil ajudar

Comment: @IvanSilva, editei a pergunta com a Stacktrace

Comment: Vamos ver o que descobrimos

Comment: Debuga até achar o ponto que ta quebrando.

Comment: Onde tá a implementação de EnderecoPessoaDaoImpl?

Comment: @IvanSilva, editei a pergunta com a implementação

Comment: Estou olhando o stack trace. O que há na linha 199 de DaoGenericoImp.java? Também ajuda se ficar mais claro qual é a linha 492 de RegistroOnlineEmpresaController.java (pois há mais de uma chamada a salvar() ali)

Comment: @marcus, Na linha 199 tem isso: getEntityManager().persist(object);
e na linha 492 de RegistroOnlineEmpresaController tem isso:        enderecoPessoaDao.salvar(enderecoEmpresa);

Comment: Se nenhuma das variáveis óbvias dessas duas linhas (enderecoEmpresa, object, enderecoPessoaDao, entityManager, etc.) é null, tente olhar para o EnderecoId. Eu vi que ele foi construído com o construtor default e você chamou o setPessoa, então pode estar faltando o setTipoEndereco.

Comment: Você só recebe o erro quando invoca `DaoGenericoImp.salvar()`? Confesso que não consegui entender completamente o código, mas se possível, verifica isso

Comment: em qual classe está o método   public void salvarRegistro()  ?

Comment: @marcus, era isso mesmo. Estava faltando o setTipoEndereco()

Comment: @JulianaMarques, obrigado por voltar aqui e avisar! Vou transformar o comentário numa resposta.

Comment: Eu que agradeço @marcus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(o problema foi resolvido nos comentários, vou criar uma resposta mais completa para ficar organizado).

Primeiro olhei o stack trace e vi quais eram as linhas do seu código apontadas (haverá várias chamadas do framework, por isso procure as suas).

Encontrei `br.org.web.servicosOnline.controller.RegistroOnlineEmpresaController.salvarRegistro(RegistroOnlineEmpresaController.java:492)` e `br.org.web.dao.impl.DaoGenericoImp.salvar(DaoGenericoImp.java:199)` que, como você informou, contêm:

`enderecoPessoaDao.salvar(enderecoEmpresa);`

e

`getEntityManager().persist(object);`

Depois é necessário ver se alguma dessas variáveis é ou poderia ser null (sob alguma circunstância), como enderecoPessoaDao, enderecoEmpresa, o retorno de getEntityManager() ou object.

Como nenhuma é null e o erro parece estar dentro do persist(), temos que testar outra hipótese: pode ser que a chave primária não esteja setada. Vi que EnderecoPessoa tem uma chave composta representada por EnderecoId. O construtor usado é o default:

`new EnderecoPessoa()`

que chama

`new EnderecoId();`

Não foi postado o código de EnderecoId, mas se ele simplesmente deixar os seus campos null e eles não forem setados depois da construção, o objeto resultante pode ser inválido para o persist(). Encontrei no código a chamada a setPessoa(), então supus que a falta de setTipoEndereco() (o outro campo da chave composta) poderia ser a causa do erro.

E realmente era isso (conforme comentário nesta questão), então a solução mais simples é **chamar setTipoEndereco()** antes do persist().

Sempre que possível, os construtores devem deixar o objeto num estado válido/consistente. O `new EnderecoId()` cria um ID inválido que causa NullPointerException mais à frente se não forem setados todos os seus campos manualmente. Talvez neste caso não haja o que fazer, mas vale a pena fazer um teste: se o persist() aceitar id null com um erro "amigável" (como: "É necessário setar o @Id da entidade antes de salvar"), é preferível reorganizar os construtores de modo que um objeto obrigatoriamente tenha ID null (sem chamar new EnderecoId()) ou então tenha um EnderecoId completo e nunca parcial. Mas claro, talvez isso apenas mude o local do NullPointerException, o que não ajuda muito. Nesse caso o melhor a fazer é colocar um comentário "Não esqueça de setar o ID composto! :-)".